# JSONP response download as a file?

Tags: php, codeigniter

When I call webservices and response convert into jsonp format, at that time response come correctly but it is download as a file. File format is not displayed. Just download file. I try below code.

```
$result = array(
    'Result'=>'Error',
    'ErrorMessage'=>'Please enter valid Data
);

header('Content-type: application/jsonp');
return json_encode($result);
```

I also try with echo and print replace of return keyword.

Comment: This is not jsonp what you return. It is json. This does not explain the effect you get, but I wanted to mention that...

Comment: 1.) this is no jsnop, its json and
2.) don't use internet explorer for developing

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = array(
    'Result'=>'Error',
    'ErrorMessage'=>'Please enter valid Data
);

$this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($result ));
```

Comment: get error
<div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: 4096</p>
<p>Message:  Object of class CI_Output could not be converted to string</p>
<p>Filename: default/defaultratemodel.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 23</p>

</div>{"Result":"Error","ErrorMessage":"Please enter valid SCAC Code like TOWN, PITD, FDEX, ODFL, AVRT, DAFG, EXLA, DAYL, SMTL, SHIF, HMES, CEFL, RRUN, AAAC, SAIA, NPME, XGSI, CLNI, CTII, ABFS, CNWY, CUST, DHRN, YRCL, RLCA,  HMESS, FTIC, NEMF, FORW, FRTS, CRGM, CRST, NEBT, FFEX, PFCR, RIST, STDF"}

Comment: I need only....

{"Result":"Error","ErrorMessage":"Please enter valid SCAC Code like TOWN, PITD, FDEX, ODFL, AVRT, DAFG, EXLA, DAYL, SMTL, SHIF, HMES, CEFL, RRUN, AAAC, SAIA, NPME, XGSI, CLNI, CTII, ABFS, CNWY, CUST, DHRN, YRCL, RLCA,  HMESS, FTIC, NEMF, FORW, FRTS, CRGM, CRST, NEBT, FFEX, PFCR, RIST, STDF"}

Comment: try this   `header('Content-Type: application / x - json;charset = utf-8');`
            `echo(json_encode("true"));`

Comment: It's not working. for ex i need like this...{"Result":"Error"}